# How can I install Ubuntu in BlackBerry Playbook?

Tags: installation, system, tablet, blackberry, ubuntu-touch

I have a Blackberry Playbook. I loved the Blackberry OS at first, but now I feel constrained by the lack of applications and functions. I assume that, by installing Ubuntu on my tablet, will give me the freedom of a full-featured OS.

Then, how can I install it on my Playbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The playbook is not going to be supported as mentioned [here at Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/TabletList) (under the heading "OMAP 4").